# How can I create ApnSetting object?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, telephony

I am trying to create an **ApnSetting** object, but result is always **null**.

```
using var apn = new ApnSetting.Builder();
apn.SetEntryName("APN name");
apn.SetApnName("some.apn");
var test = apn.Build();
```

The **test** variable is always **null**. Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting.Builder) says that there have to be:

- apnTypeBitmask
- apnName
- entryName

I can't find any way how to set the APN type and that's probably the reason why the result is **null**. There should be something like `apn.SetApnTypeBitmask(ApnType.Default);`, but it is not or I can't find it.

Comment: have you try use this ?apn = new ApnSetting.Builder() .setApnTypeBitmask(ApnSetting.TYPE_DEFAULT | ApnSetting.TYPE_MMS) .setApnName("apn.example.com") .setEntryName("Example Carrier APN") .setMmsc(Uri.parse("http://mms.example.com:8002")) .setMmsProxyAddress(mmsProxy) .setMmsProxyPort(8799) .build();

Comment: I think you missed that I have already referred to the documentation. This question is about how to do it in Xamarin Android. There is no SetApnTypeBitmask() method.

Answer (score -1):

You can invoke native platform functionality from shared code in xamarin through dependency service link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Create an interface like:

```
public interface ICreateApn
{
   public void CreateApn(string nameA,stringB ...... );
}
```

Then Implement the interface on andriod like:

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (CreateApn))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.iOS
{
    public class CreateApn : ICreateApn
    {public void CreateApn(string nameA,stringB ...... )
{
.
.
.
}


}}
```